# Bash script to update last character

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have one text file which ends with two kinds of strings, either like 100m, 200m or like 6, 7 etc.
When the last string does not contain the "m" character, the bash script should multiply it with 1024 and append with m. No change should happen to the lines ending with m.

I have tried multiple if, else clause with awk but not able to find proper result. Please help. For security reason, I can't share the file but providing a sample below

## Input file

```
fwhjgqdgqdg 100m
gdjegdegge 200m
fdfqwkdgqwdgqwdgh 300m
fhwfgwgdgw1 8998m
tdfdyfdgeu 6
feuegdhe 2
ffhevjevf 0
jhedhevhjkd 0
```

## output should be

```
fwhjgqdgqdg 100m
gdjegdegge 200m
fdfqwkdgqwdgqwdgh 300m
fhwfgwgdgw1 8998m
tdfdyfdgeu 6124m
feuegdhe 2048m
ffhevjevf 0m
jhedhevhjkd 0m
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: By seeing your propfile @Subit Das same to know you hardly show your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem and you NEVER select an answer as correct one. Kindly try to do both the things for your questions.

Comment: I will do so. I was in doubt, whether to put this in stackoverflow or not. After struggling for few hours, I decided to put it. I asked for awk because BC is not supported in my linux environment. I was searching for using if else clause inside awk. I should not have asked direct requirement. I should have asked to understand the concept first like what majorities are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following -

```
$ awk '$NF !~ /m/{$NF = ($NF * 1024) "m"} 1' file
fwhjgqdgqdg 100m
gdjegdegge 200m
fdfqwkdgqwdgqwdgh 300m
fhwfgwgdgw1 8998m
tdfdyfdgeu 6144m
feuegdhe 2048m
ffhevjevf 0m
jhedhevhjkd 0m
```

`$NF` is the value of the last field on the record (line). If it doesn't contain an `m` then multiply by 1024 and concatenate an `m`. The `1` at the end is a true condition which causes awk to invoke it's default action of printing the record.

Comment: almost same - `awk '/m$/{print} /[0-9]$/{ print $1 " " $2*1024 "m" }'`. I don't like that it makes so many assumptions, but hey, specs is specs, yes? :D

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v var="1024" -v field="2" -v char="m" '$field !~ char{$field= ($field * 1024) char} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** I have created variables named `var`: which will have value which you want to multiply, `field` you can mention field number here on which field you want to put check, `char` which character you want to check is present in line or not.

You could change these values as per your need too. Now inside `awk` command I am checking condition if a line's `$field` is NOT having `var` value then do following, which is to multiple field's value with value of variable var and concatenate value of variable `char`.

Finally mentioing `1` will print edited/non-edited line for Input_file.

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl

```
perl -pe ' s/(\d+)$/1024*$1/ge and s/$/m/ '
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat subit.txt
fwhjgqdgqdg 100m
gdjegdegge 200m
fdfqwkdgqwdgqwdgh 300m
fhwfgwgdgw1 8998m
tdfdyfdgeu 6
feuegdhe 2
ffhevjevf 0
jhedhevhjkd 0

$ perl -pe ' s/(\d+)$/1024*$1/ge and s/$/m/ ' subit.txt
fwhjgqdgqdg 100m
gdjegdegge 200m
fdfqwkdgqwdgqwdgh 300m
fhwfgwgdgw1 8998m
tdfdyfdgeu 6144m
feuegdhe 2048m
ffhevjevf 0m
jhedhevhjkd 0m

$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could have tried if my environment supported perl.